# What's the difference between chkconfig on vs chkconfig --add?

Tags: chkconfig

Whats the difference between using chkconfig on and using chkconfig --add?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`chkconfig --add` adds a *new* service to the list of services managed by `chkconfig`. I believe `--add` is an implicit `on`.

`chkconfig on` sets the runlevel for the service.

That said, I tend to use `chkconfig -add` for adding new services to a system, but `ntsysv` to manage them (on RHEL-like systems).

Comment: I ran this chkconfig ntpd on without ever running --add and that seemed to work fine.

Comment: `chkconfig --add` is for adding *new* services; e.g. services or daemons that are not already registered on the server. For instance, if I download software that doesn't have an init script and I write one... I would have to place that script in `/etc/init.d/` and run `chkconfig --add` to allow it to be managed in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

In Redhat/CentOS, there is one line in the init script which looks like

```
# chkconfig: - 65 10
```

If you use --add when the first arg of above line is "-", this adds no start links, only the kill links. So for --add to work, you have to edit the init script and change to e.g.

```
# chkconfig: 345 65 10
```

But if chkconfig --add ... was executed with the "-" as first arg (which is mostly the case from rpm post script):
Changing afterwards the first arg and reexecute chkconfig --add has no effect as long as the
kill links are present. In this case --list shows off for all runlevel:

```
chkconfig --list saslauthd
saslauthd       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off    4:off    5:off    6:off
```

To make --add work in this case, you first have to use --del, then the output of --list is:

```
chkconfig --list saslauthd
service saslauthd supports chkconfig, but is not referenced in any runlevel (run 'chkconfig --add saslauthd')
```

Now you can use --add and it has the desired effect.

Alternatively you can use "on" with the --level argument to avoid the need of editing the init script and to avoid first --del followed by --add.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you running?  If you run chkconfig with only a service name as an argument, I believe RHEL's chkconfig simply checks if that service is set to run at which ever run level you are currently running (said Dr. Suess).